Unusual chip antenna feed impedance matching
I'm designing a PCB with a RFANT3216120A1T ceramic SMD chip Bluetooth antenna.
The part is somewhat poorly documented and does not state the antenna impedance. The datasheet shows a test board with an unfamiliar matching network:

Since the 'Series 2' is quoted as unpopulated (maybe it's supposed to be shorted instead?), I have assumed that it is supposed to act as a coplanar capacitor equal to about 0.105 pF (assuming a coplanar length of an average of the feed line and solder pad widths and Dk = 4.6). This, should then correspond to an antenna impedance of about 50 + j580 Ohm. I also considered that this feed network is supposed to act as a resonant filter, but with the assumed coplanar capacitance it's off by an order of magnitude almost (considering 2.45 GHz target).
Are my assumptions and reasoning valid or did I misinterpret the feed and matching network here? What would be the reason behind this kind of matching network?

Your assumptions are right, the fact that there is just a pad implies that the series 1 is some sort of cap implemented by layout.
I don't agree with your calculation of impedance though. I think frequency needs to be considered. I would look at impedance if capacitor as 1/jwC, which is the point here. At low frequenies this will be highZ, at high frequencies it will be a short circuit. In between it has some impedance and apparently it   acts like matching circuit.
I personally would avoid this kind of matching and i would suggest getting a sample of this antenna and measuring S11 and impedance with VNA on this reference design and series 1 = 0R.
If series 1 really needs to be a cap i suggest using a cap if certain defined value, preferably NP0 ceramics.
While designing the board to measure the impedance, any changes in stackup planned for the final design could be implemented, e.g. making board desired thickness,... If this is different from reference design, also the width of the transmission line might need to change.

Maybe I didn't describe the obtained impedance value enough. What I did is calculate the coplanar capacitance and then plot the network and transmission line on a Smith chart. The impedance I quoted was what the antenna would need to have in order to match the entire thing to 50 Ohm. I agree that the only reliable way is to use a VNA, which I already ordered but I was hoping to get an approximate idea until it arrives. Thanks for the insight.
